# Site load time increased

Tags: performance, server-load

My WordPress site(urchd.com) load time increased and sometimes I face error 524 due to some queries execution time exceeds 21 seconds. I already tried contacting my hosting provider they say that you need to optimize the queries and reduce the load on the server. Can anyone guide me on how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the WP database is a bit 'cluttered' with draft posts and other things.

I'd recommend an optimizing plugin to optimize the WP database.

But it also depends on your traffic. Maybe the amount of traffic indicates a need to upgrade your hosting plan from a shared server to the next level.